# Table rates shipping method with weight vs destination in Magento

Tags: magento

In Magento Table rates Shipping method when I set condition say Weight vs. Destination and I fill up the tablerates.csv file I found a column Weight (and above). That means you have to manually enter values for each step like 1kg and above, 2 kg and above...

My Question is:

If I don't want to set maximum weight and a fixed amount will be charged for every additional 1kg after the 1st 1kg, Then how do I set up?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Owebia Shipping instead of Magento Tablerate.

- In System=>Configuration, find the Sales=>Shipping Method tab.
- Next open Owebia shipping options (1, 2 or 3), enable it and give it a name.

In "Configuration", you can setup something like :

```
#Formula:
{
    code: "yourcode",
    label: "Your Label"
    fees: "5+{cart.weight}*1.5"
}
```

With this rule :

- 5 is fixed amout;
- 1.5 is the cart weight's multiplier.

For instance with a 3kg cart, a value of 9.5 will be applied for shipping fees (5 + 3 x 1.5).

Hope it helps.